# Photoshop: how to toggle rulers

Tags: adobe-photoshop, shortcuts

I'm using a lot of rulers and sometimes I want to see the documents without the rulers.

Is there any button to press that can toggle these for me? I'm not talking about <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. I need to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.